# sessionStorage Data Sharing with Completely Separate Sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, session-storage

Newbie here,

Could use some help.

User A logs into system.  sessionStorage data is added for User A as you would expect.
User B logs into system.  sessionStorage data is added for User B as you would expect.
Problem: User A now shows User B sessionStorage data when opening sessionStorage.  Who ever logs in last has their sessionStorage data showing up instead of the actual logged in user.

Why is the most recent logged in user's sessionStorage data appearing in other user's sessionStorage?

Thanks in advance for your help!

a

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of things causing this.

1. You could be improperly terminating a user session - You should terminate/clear any of the key-pairs in the 'session' or 'local' on logout to see if that can narrow down the issue.
2. If you are using any third party libraries to do some of the heavy lifting, they could be the culprit.

But I would try addressing the problem with the first approach that I mentioned. That will at least narrow everything down.

Comment: ok...but what if they're not logged out yet?  Shouldn't both sessions be treated independently?

Comment: Not using any third party stuff at all.  Just the standard calls to setItem and removeItem.

Comment: I am confused. Normally session storage refers to the storage on someone's browser. Are you having multiple logins from the same browser simultaneously?

Comment: Nope.  Two separate browsers in two separate locations.  I'm logged in locally on my current machine, then from a remote server in a different state.  When I log into the second machine, the sessionStorage data shows the most recently logged in user.  Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue.  You guys got me thinking.

I was emitting the socket messages using io.emit(), which sends to "all clients."  Once I set the socket to emit private messages to sessionStorage it resolved it.

Thanks all.